# Setting value to the default specified in the table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table (all names are for illustration purposes, the original names have been withheld):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSomeName](
    [ChangeDate] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Manual')
)
```

I would like to write a stored proc like:

```
CREATE PROC p_PutToTable
(
    @ID [INT], 
    @ChangeDate [date] = NULL,
    @Source [varchar] (100) = NULL
)
AS BEGIN
  MERGE tblSomeName as tgt
  USING (SELECT ...
```

If the @Source is NULL I would like to have the stored proc use the default from the table. I would like to avoid hard-coding the default specified in the table in yet another place, i.e. this stored proc. Maybe somehow query the default from the table definition? (Hoping there's a better way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create your default so that is has a name this becomes pretty easy. You could do by changing the way you create your table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSomeName](
    [ChangeDate] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL
)

alter table tblSomeName
add constraint DF_tblSomeName DEFAULT ('Manual') FOR [Source]
```

Now we know with certainty what the name of the constraint is so we can easily find it.

Your procedure could be something like this.

```
CREATE PROC p_PutToTable
(
    @ID [INT], 
    @ChangeDate [date] = NULL,
    @Source [varchar] (100) = NULL
)
AS BEGIN


    if @Source IS NULL
        select @Source = replace(replace(replace(definition, '(', ''), ')', ''), '''', '')
        from sys.default_constraints
        where name = 'DF_tblSomeName'

    --The rest of your code here

END
```

Comment: I like this idea. This is great, didn't think of it.

Comment: No, you don't know with certainty what the constraint name is.This is not a good solution. What if the default was defined in-line with the column definition? What if someone drops the constraint and creates a new one with a different name? A good solution would be to query knowing only the *column* and *table* names.

Comment: @Bohemian - In the example posted I absolutely do know what the name of the constraint is. I agree that a better solution would be to query using the column and table names but that doesn't mean this is a bad solution.

Comment: @sean it's "bad" because it's brittle, and importantly if the name changes no errors will be thrown and the behaviour of the system will silently change

Comment: @Bohemian I agree it is brittle. But the same argument you make about the name of the constraint can be made the other way. If you change the query to look at the constraints by table and column name it could just as easily break if either of those is changed. Seems that isn't really any better. ;)

Comment: @Sean I disagree. The table name and column will not change, and *should* not change, because that is the API for the data - the names form part of the contract offered by the database. If they did chang, everything using the tables would instantly break, and break loudly. Because constraint names are irrelevant to the data API (they are an concern internal to the database), they *can* change and are allowed to change (or even disappear entirely) without any failures or indication they have changed, because the database's API is unaffected.